# One time password sharing over local network

Tags: networking, security, file-sharing

I am responsible for the security of a company where passwords are currently stored locally with a password manager, but if another employee needs a password, they are shared via cloud based programs like Slack or Teams, which I want to prevent.

My idea was a local server that removes messages once they have been read or stored for more than 1 minute. (I don't want a network-based password storage, just a way to securely share passwords over the network.)

Does anyone have recommendations/experience with such software or is the idea generally stupid?

Comment: maybe you want something like this: https://yopass.se/#/ (project here https://github.com/jhaals/yopass )

Comment: I'll try it out, thank you!

Comment: The premise is bad. Its like putting a very solid steel door next to a thin glass window. Once the traffic can be sniffed it does not matter if it appears for 1 minute of 1 hour.

Answer (score 2):

> passwords are currently stored locally with a password manager

Not ideal, but better than nothing.

> if another employee needs a password, they are shared via cloud based programs ...

I would suggest that you need a better password management solution, one that gives people access to the credentials they need to access *without* them having to keep local, *uncontrolled* copies of passwords.
It also begs the question why you're not tying this access into Active Directory and giving known [groups of] individuals access to the things they need through that, instead of handing out "Magic Keys" that get *anyone who holds them* into whatever they want, with little or no fear of identification.

You cannot Police against stupidity.

You can, however, give them a *better* way of doing what they need to do which, I'm sorry to say, is largely what you say you *don't* want to do - using a network or cloud-based password management application.

You lose nothing, but gain security, robustness, and individual accountability for those who use it.